# Simple HTML Parser PHP Remove All Table Rows Except First

Tags: php, parsing

I have the following table I need to parse. How do I remove all rows except for the first one (Table Headings), then inject more rows from a variable underneath the first row?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
    <th>Column 5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
    <td>Column 4</td>
    <td>Column 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT :** The following is the code I have so far. It add a new row, but doesn't remove all others (except the first) first. Also, I'm not sure if this is the best way this can be done, or if's its best to use a select (Like in jQuery).

```
$html = str_get_html($str);

$firstTr = true;

foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr) {
  if(!$firstTr) {
    echo '<tr>
              <td>Extra Row</td>
          </tr>';
  }
  else {
    $firstTr = false;
  }
}

echo $html;
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Original Post Updated - Contains post so far!

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you need

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
});
</script>
```

[Jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2WC9U/)